# Qt C++ List of fonts in QListView or QListWidget and represent them as checkboxes

Tags: c++, qt

I need to make list of all fonts which are installed on system. Then user can select up to 4 fonts, but my idea was to input those fonts in list as checkboxes. Can you help me with this, or maybe someone has better and easier idea for this.

Comment: Show what you have done, what went wrong and we can help you.

Comment: @IanMedeiros Well, I haven't done anything, I need idea and maybe pseudocode. I have big application, and I only need this part to finish it, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I don't know how to load all system fonts into QListView or QListWidget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asked two completely different questions in one, the first: "QListView or QListWidget and represent them as checkboxes" has been asked and answered many times on this site - please use the search function.  Here's [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369300/how-can-i-add-a-checkbox-radio-botton-to-qtablewidget).

The second: "I need to make list of all fonts which are installed on system.", use `QFontDatabase` ([docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfontdatabase.html#details)) for that.